# Android - dimming screen from service

Tags: android, screen

I have a service which detects certain system events, like certain hour of the day. I would like my service to (when criteria is met) to dim user screen.

So far, looking though internet and StackOverflow i found a plenty of solutions relying on "getWindow()" which means my app must have a running foreground activity in order to achieve this.

If i just have a service which should put a system-wide screen brightness to, say, 30%, what needs to be done? I don't think it's very similar to changing brightness "locally" (just for my own app).

My idea was obtaining a "window" of current foreground app, but i'm not very sure if that's even possible :\

Can someone give me some hint or help please, all my searches ended with "you need to call "getWindow()" of your own app"?

Comment: Overall screen brightness might be controlled [via `SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS). If so, in principle, you can change that if you hold the `WRITE_SYSTEM_SETTINGS` permission. However, that's not an easy permission to obtain, and you'll be overriding the user's normal brightness controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is

```
System.putInt(contentResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness)
```

But you also need permissions
Pre api 23

```
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
```

Comment: Actually, this works as from service i can call "getContentResolver()"! Thanks!